# How to correctly declare a Polygon message

Tags: ros, c++, message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hellow,

Easy question, I'm not able to declare a Polygone message that does not core dump. Here is my code for now :

```
geometry_msgs::Point32 tl;
polyStamp.polygon.points[0]=tl;
```

I have the doc of the [Polygon Stamped](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/PolygonStamped.html) and the [Polygon](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Polygon.html) but I guess I'm reading it really badly.

I tried declaring a table of Point32 as well and directly passing it to polygon.points but it wont compile then.

Thanks a lot for any answer.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145086/how-to-correctly-declare-a-polygon-message/) by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1172 on 2014-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to pre-allocate the points array before you assign members into it, or use a function that does the appropriate bounds-checking and resize for you. In particular, arrays in ROS messages in C++ are implemented as std::vectors, and [std::vector::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/) doesn't do any bounds checking.

If you just want to append items to your array, try:

```
geometry_msgs::Point32 tl;
polyStamp.polygon.points.push_back(tl);
```

If you already know how big your array is going to be, and you want to assign to specific indicies, try:

```
geometry_msgs::Point32 tl;
polyStamp.polygon.points.reserve(10); // ensure that there will be space for at least 10 points
polyStamp.polygon.points[0]=tl;
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Maya](https://answers.ros.org/users/12786/maya/) on 2014-03-26**:
Thanks a lot ! I didn't realize they were implemented as vectors !